# Strange behaviour in MVC 4 partial view

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, listbox, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I got this simple partial view

```
@ModelType someModel

<div>
    @Code
        Dim list = //some Ienumerable of SelectListItem
        Html.ListBox("MappingFields", list)
    End Code
</div>
```

The same code works in a main view nicely. But when I shift it to a partial view and have an action in the main controller as:

```
    Function RetrurnMyPartialView(id As String) As PartialViewResult
        //get model for id
        Return PartialView("_partialView", model)
    End Function
```

It is not working!!

I got another partial view with similar implementation and is working fine. Can a `ListBox` be not used in partial views?

This wasted almost a day. The resulting html for the partial view is an empty div like:

```
<div>

</div>
```

I tried to debug, and the model, list items and everything are binding properly.

Please help..Thank you.

Comment: just post code of main view from where partialview is loaded..

Comment: You can see it in the controller code (2nd codeblock above). The main view code is irrelevant as typing the url directly in the browser is giving same result -empty div. `localhost:03280/main/RetrurnMyPartialView/1` (this is an example url)

Comment: I have never used Code.  Try building the Ienumerable list on your controller and passing it through your model to the partial.  Remove the Code and just have @Html.ListBox("MappingFields", Model.list)

Comment: `@Html.ListBox()` is not working in the partial view. I have gone for a workaround. Please check the thread http://forums.asp.net/p/2001901/5754171.aspx?Re+Strange+behaviour+in+MVC+4+partial+view
TY :)